# Formula for dependent Drop-down list from table data in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

Excel Noob here.

I am trying to create a dropdown list based on a cell value. The data for the dropdown list is in a table called "Data". I want to populate a drop-down box with values based on a column (Status) in the data table. Status Column has 4  values: Open, Closed, Open-Future, Hold. When the Open Status is selected, I would like the dropdown to populate the ticket numbers associated with that status, but I am unable to achieve it.

The drop-down is located in another tab, where the information in the table is presented in a page view format per ticket. Otherwise, when presenting the information, I have to scroll rows and columns when presenting the details of a ticket.

The table structure is as below;
Column 1: Ticket No
Column 2: Issue Title
Column 3: Description
Column 4: Status and other columns applicable to the ticket

I tried, conditional drop-down list examples described [here](https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html) but it did not work. My guess is due to the data structure in my table.
Unfortunately, I am unable to change the column structure nor use VBA to address the issue and relying on a magic formula.

Hope I explained the issue with relevant details, please let me know if you need further information to derive to a solution.
Note: I don't see an easy way to attach the sample document, as it's work computer and restrictions are put around using most of the file-sharing websites. So I have uploaded the screenshot of the spreadsheets [refer to attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe1wj.jpg)

Thanks
Al Sheik

Comment: are you able to insert a helper column to your data table and sort the data table by Status?

Comment: Hi Terry, thank you for your response. I should be able to sort this table based on status. That shouldn’t be an issue. Could you please further expand on the helper column thought ? I should be able to it as I manager it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have sorted your `Data` table by **Status**, you can insert a helper column as shown below:

[image: Example]

The formula in Cell `C2` is

```
=IF(B2=Select_Status,ROW()-1,"")
```

where **Select_Status** is the name I gave to the cell where your primary drop down list sits. In my example it is cell `G2`.

> The logic is to return the row position of the ticket number based on the status you selected.

Next, create a new **named range** using the following formula. In my example I have named it as **FilteredList**.

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MIN(FilteredTN),,COUNTIF(FilteredTN,">0"))
```

[image: FilteredList]

Then you can use this named range in your secondary drop down list:

[image: Drop Down List]

Here is what you should get:

[image: Result]

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: This looks great. I read through the solution and looks like it will solve the issue. However, I don’t have access to work computer now, let me check this out first thing first and update you. Thank you so much for thinking of a workable solution.

Comment: Hi Terry, I just tested the solution and it works like a charm. Thanks for helping out. Legend!

Comment: @Alsheik my pleasure :)